# Как сделать выполнение многодневной тренировки в тренажерном зале?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Всем доброго вечера! В общем, проблема такая: делаю приложение посвященное тренировкам в тренажерном зале, не знаю как реализовать процесс многодневных тренировок в тренажерном зале. Например, чтобы в первый день, выполняя несколько упражнений, ставить галочки, что упражнения выполнены. Потом выходить из него, тем самым сохраняя те галочки, которые были поставлены до этого. И чтобы потом начинался второй день тренировок, то есть сохраняется информация, что мы уже первый день тренировок по программе сделали.
Не прошу прям досконально объяснить, что и как, хотя бы подбросьте несколько идей или источники, которые мне помогут.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Я считаю вопрос не связан с программированием.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Продумайте интерфейс. Какие элементы (`View`) потребуются для этого. Какая информация будет находится в приложении. Как вы будете ее добавлять, обновлять, удалять. Создайте sqLite базу данных, пусть нужная информация хранится там. Раз у вас некие периоды тренировок, значит как минимум этот период должен как-то идентифицироваться в БД. Так же и там же определить каждый день тренировок в рамках этого периода. Упражнения соответственно тоже.

Чем тщательнее вы продумаете, что хотите получить в результате, тем легче и быстрее получится эту затею реализовать. `RuSO` в помощь.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно как-нибудь сохранить информацию о выполненных упражнениях. На эту тему [есть отдельный раздел](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html) в справке для разработчиков андроид-приложений. Там описаны три метода:

1. [Сохранение наборов «ключ-значение»](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html). Наиболее простой метод, однако не очень подходит при больших объёмах данных.
2. [Метод сохранения в файл](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html). Мне кажется, этот метод является наиболее подходящим для вашего случая, так как он достаточно простой и в то же время достаточно гибкий.
3. [Использование базы данных](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html). Наиболее правильный метод, однако придётся научиться работать с базами данных, что, однако, достаточно полезно.

Сохранить данные о тренировках в файл можно, например, преобразовав их в `json` с помощью библиотеки [`gson`](https://github.com/google/gson).

Comment: самым подходящим в этом случае будет метод сохранения в БД (SQLite или какая то из ORM, вроде Realm), так как наверняка требуется выборка за определенные периоды, по определенным полям и тп статистические данные.

Comment: @pavlofff, вы правы. Я написал что метод сохранения в файл наиболее подходящий так как, вероятно, автор вопроса пока что не умеет работать с базами данных.

Comment: @pavlofff Да, действительно, я пока не умею работать с БД. Попроще будет работать с сохранением в файл, да? А, например, я смогу сохранять в файл упражнения и программы тренировок, которые мне будут нужны?

Comment: @СальвадорДали, вы можете сохранить в файл всё, что захотите. Допустим вся информация вашей программы описывается объектом класса `State`. В нём есть поля, которые, например, представляют собой другие классы вашей программы, в которых тоже есть поля и т. д. Можно вручную сохранить всю информацию в файл (написать много кода для сохранения каждого кусочка состояния). Но куда более простой способ — использовать библиотеку Gson, примерно так: `new Gson().toJson(state)` — получится json строка, которую можно записать в файл.

Comment: @СальвадорДали хороший повод научится работать с БД. Да, организация правильной структуры БД и составление запросов к ней тема довольно сложная, но использование в вашей задачи записи в файл заведомо худшее решение и в конечном итоге вы придете к тому, что все нужно переделать на БД - зачем оттягивать неизбежное. Для понимания организации работы с БД рекомендую почитать замечательную книгу, написанную (как и все издания O'Reilly) живым и понятным языком, для новичков: Бейли Л. - Изучаем SQL  - 2012г., она не о Android, но очень поможет понять как устроить БД и как правильно с ней работать.

Comment: @Дмитрий Считаете, лучше с бд работать, да? Получается, бд будет храниться во внутренней памяти проекта? Или надо будет какое-то ПО еще устанавливать?

Comment: @Дмитрий составить правильную структуру БД и корректный запрос - это далеко не статья из ответа, этому вообще то годами учатся (и не все успешно) :)

Comment: @pavlofff, да, вы опять правы).

Comment: @СальвадорДали поддержка SQLite встроена в API Android, ничего дополнительно устанавливать не нужно. Но вам скорее всего понадобится менеджер баз SQLite на компьютере для тестов запросов

Comment: @pavlofff Спасибо за вышеупомянутую книгу. Создам я,например, БД с упражнениями, программами тренировок, тренировочными днями и т.д. Смогу я,например, вот так сделать: используя БД, расписать программу тренировок на 7 дней, и на каждый день расписать упражнения, которые надо будет выполнить?

Comment: @СальвадорДали Вы сможете сделать все, что вам будет нужно, БД и придуманы для организации такого типа данных, а почитав книгу, узнаете, как правильно, она содержит множество примеров. Менеджеров баз данных SQLite очень много, я использую [SQLite Expert **personal**](http://www.sqliteexpert.com/index.html) (бесплатная версия, но имеет все необходимое и даже больше).  Так же менеджер на ПК удобно использовать для первоначального заполнения базы данными.

Comment: @ pavlofff Я не могу понять, где я буду создавать бд: в самом коде (в самой Android Studio) или в менеджере? Если создам бд полностью в менеджере, то как я буду забирать данные в мое приложение?